# "halten VON" vs. "halten FÜR"

Tags: expression

Ich habe die Antwort von der Verschiedenheit von "halten von" und "halten für" nicht gefunden... Eigentlich, habe ich manche Erklärungen gelesen, aber sie haben keinen direkten Vergleich darüber gemacht. Meine Fragen:

- Was halten Sie davon? = Ist das wichtig für Sie? oder Was ist deine Meinung nach...?

  - Ich halte viel davon = Das ist sehr wichtig für mich
  - Ich halte wenig davon = Das ist nicht sehr wichtig für mich
  - Ich halte nichts davon = Das ist überhaupt nicht wichtig für mich

Stimmt?

Was "halten für" angeht, bedeutet das "Was denkst/glaubst du daran?"

- Sie hat es nicht für möglich gehalten = Sie hat es gedacht, dass etwas unmöglich war?

Comment: These are completely orthogonal usages.

Comment: Was hälst du von AfD-Wählern? Abstand!

Answer (score 4):

Hier sind einige Sätze, die dir vielleicht helfen, den Unterschied zu verstehen:

- Ich halte nichts davon = Ich habe eine schlelchte Meinung davon. Ich schätze es gering.
- Ich halte viel davon = Ich habe eine gute Meinung davon. Ich schätze es (hoch).
- Ich halte das für schön = Ich finde, dass es schön ist.
- Ich halte das für hässlich = Ich finde, dass es hässlich ist.
- Ich halte dich für einen Esel = Ich finde, dass du dumm und unsympathisch bist.
- Ich halte dich für ein Genie = Ich glaube, dass du extrem klug bist.
- Ich halte nichts von Genies = Ich habe eine schlechte Meinung von Genies. Ich mag keine Genies.
- Ich halte viel von Eseln = Ich finde Esel interessante, liebenswerte, achtenswerte Tiere.
- Ich halte nichts von Leuten, die sich für Genies halten = Ich habe keine gute Meinung von Leuten, die glauben, sie seien Genies.
- Es gibt Leute, die halten sich für Genies. = Es gibt Leute, die glauben von sich selbst, sie seien Genies.

Comment: Danke Christian! Die Sätze waren tatsächlich sehr hilfreich!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Bei `halten von` geht es mehrheitlich um deine Meinung zu jemanden oder etwas.

> Was hältst du von dieser Kette?

Bei `halten für` geht es mehrheitlich um Verwechslungen. Zum Beispiel du verwechselst jemanden.

> Tut mir leid, ich habe dich für meine Mutter gehalten.

**English**

`halten von` is mostly about your opinion of someone or something.

> Was hältst du von dieser Kette?

`halten für` is about confusion. For example you thought the woman is your mother.

> Tut mir leid, ich habe dich für meine Mutter gehalten.

Comment: Hint: code formatting makes texts extremely difficult to impossible to read on mobile devices as there’s no line-break and longer text simply disappears. Use the “quote” or other formatting instead, please.

Comment: Btw, one language should be sufficient. (Using German + English is not forbidden however.) Rule of thumb: Use the asker’s language. We don’t close duplicates posts in different languages, the reasoning can be found on [Meta].

Comment: Dass "halten für" sich großteils auf Verwechslungen bezieht, _halte ich für ungenau_. Die Bedeutung ist von "X für Y halten" ist "glauben, dass X  Y ist" (auch wenn es gerade noch nicht sicher festgestellt werden kann oder eine subjektive Einschätzung ist). Die Einschätzung kann zutreffen oder auch nicht.